# How to double a single TTL to link to 2 independent TTL terminal

Tags: serial, ttl

I am working on a project that needs multiple serial connection between mcu sensors .

In order to send data by ttl serial from 1 mcu to 2 other mcu and reverse...[image]

What is the best way to achieve this i have seen on the web that is possible with a physical switch but it's not possible for me.

I have seen a possibility to make it with multiplexer and a demux; do those ics are good to do the job; do they  affect ttl signal at 115200 baudrate.

for example in my project i have an mcu that send the same signal to rs485 to a pc and ttl to an other mcu.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this:

1. Shared bus: connect the master's TX output directly to both RX inputs, and combine the two other TX outputs with an AND gate (e.g., (SN)74LVC1G08) before going into the master's RX input.
   This means that the other two MCUs see everything that the master sends, and if the two other send at the same time, the signal gets garbled.
2. Switch: there the non-mechanical switches that work with [transmission gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate). Use any 2:1 switch like the SN74LV4053A/74LV4053. (Add pull-up resistors to the two RX inputs to prevent them from floating when they are disconnected.) Such switches have a bandwidth of many MHz.
   This requires a separate control signal.

Comment: Thank you I am going to work on a schematic and i would be glad to have your comments